# Limit involving integral with fraction

Tags: calculus

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}\cos t^2dt}{(\sin x)^2}.$$How to compute such a limit never seen that kind before

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(t)$ be any primitive function of $\cos t^2$ (note that you don't need to calculate it!). Then
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_0^{x^2} \cos t^2 dt}{(\sin x)^2}  = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x^2)-F(0)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x \cos x^2}{2x} = 1$$
where in the first equality I used $\sin x \sim x$ and the fundamental theorem of integral calculus, while in the second I used L'Hopital.

Comment: Maybe it would be cleaner to differentiate $(\sin x)^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why? I don't like computations, and in my opinion this is the easiest way to get the result with the smallest amount of computation.

Comment: The intuition of many students is not as well developed as yours, and it is not clear to them when a function can be safely replaced by a function of the "same size".

Comment: Not that it matters for the end result, but the last fraction should be $\frac{2x\cos x^\mathbf{4}}{2x}$. Or, as @Andre suggests, $\frac{2x\cos x^4}{2\sin x\cos x}$.

Answer (score 2):

An answer using Sandwich lemma:

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\cos x^2}{\sin^2 x}\le \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\cos t^2 dt}{\sin^2x}\le \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}$$ In the inequality above I have used the monotonicity of $\cos$ in $[0,\pi/2]$. Now note that the limits of both the lower and upper sides of the inequalities are $1$ using $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x/x=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x^2=1$. So, by [Sandwich lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) the intended limit is $1$.